# How can I make buildTriangle(lines) build a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently taking the Udacuty intro to Javascript course. This quiz that I have completed from the course, makes you create a function that takes a number and build a triangle using the number it has taken as the triangle widest width.

My question, is how can I change the code of the function buildTriangle(lines) to make function makeLine(lenghth) build a Square instead?

Thanks for your help.

```js
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

function buildTriangle(lines){
    var triangle = "";
    for(i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
        triangle += makeLine(i);
    }
    return triangle;
}


console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: just trying not to spoon feed you,, did you understand how buildTriangle is working ?

Comment: Yes I did understand.

Comment: cool people have already answered so my point is not valid , what i wanted to convey was for you to observe how width of each line is changing .. you just have to stop it from changing

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of way more complicated answers on how to make buildTriangle to repeatedly pass the same value to  makeLine. The answer was so simple, I understand the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now each time it creates a new line it looks at the "i" from the for loop to tell it how long it should make it. This means everytime it will be one longer and create a triangle. If you want it to create a square, you want every line to the same length as the height of the square. so you want to change it from `triangle += makeLine(i);` to `triangle += makeLine(lines);`. That way it every time they make a new line it's the same length as the height (lines).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of way more complicated answers on how to make buildTriangle to repeatedly pass the same value to makeLine. The answer was so simple, I understand the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`triangle += makeLine(lines);` instead of `triangle += makeLine(i);`

```js
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

function buildTriangle(lines){
    var triangle = "";
    for(i = 1; i <= lines; i++){
        triangle += makeLine(lines);
    }
    return triangle;
}


console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```